# Variable must be const in order to put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I get a compile error on Arduino 1.6.6. My code :

and I received error :

> Arduino:1.6.6 (Windows 10), Kart:"Arduino/Genuino Uno"
>
> TalkingClock:66: error: variable 'hours' must be const in order to be
>   put into read-only section by means of '**attribute**((progmem))'
>
> *hours[]  = { h12, h01, h02, h03, h04, h05, h06, h07, h08, h09, h10, h11 },
>
> TalkingClock:67: error: variable 'mTens' must be const in order to be
>   put into read-only section by means of '**attribute**((progmem))'
>
> mTens[]  = { m00, m10, m20, m30, m40, m50 },
>
> TalkingClock:68: error: variable 'mTeens' must be const in order to be
>   put into read-only section by means of '**attribute**((progmem))'
>
> mTeens[] = { m11, m12, m13, m14, m15, m16, m17, m18, m19 },
>   TalkingClock:69: error: variable 'mTenX' must be const in order to be
>   put into read-only section by means of '**attribute**((progmem))'
>
> mTenX[]  = { m0x, NULL, m2x, m3x, m4x, m5x },
>
> TalkingClock:70: error: variable 'mins' must be const in order to be
>   put into read-only section by means of '**attribute**((progmem))'
>
> mins[]   = { m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9 },
>
> TalkingClock:71: error: variable 'ampm' must be const in order to be
>   put into read-only section by means of '**attribute**((progmem))'
>   ampm[]   = { am, pm };
>
> ```
>  exit status 1
> ```

variable 'hours' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '**attribute**((progmem))'

Comment: My code :http://pasted.co/155978a8

Comment: What if you write `const char * PROGMEM hours[]  = { h12, h01, h02, h03, h04, h05, h06, h07, h08, h09, h10, h11 };`?

Comment: Before reading your comment, installed 1.0.5 version of the Arduino and I said bug fix . But at this time I encounter an error like this :

>TalkingClock.cpp.o: In function `playfile(char const*)':

>C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino/TalkingClock.ino:185: undefined reference to `playpos'
>C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino/TalkingClock.ino:185: undefined reference to `playpos'

All codes here : http://pasted.co/9df74fc9